# Сцены телеграмм-бота на nest.js

Tags: nestjs

Пытаюсь написать телеграмм-бота на nest.js. Использую библиотеку nestjs-telegraf. Не могу понять, как войти в сцену (scene) На нативном ноуде это делается легко и просто - context.scene.enter('sceneNane'). А как это сделать на nest.js?

```
app.update.ts
    import {
      Command,
      Ctx,
      InjectBot,
      Message,
      On,
      Start,
      Update
    } from 'nestjs-telegraf'
    import { Context, Markup, Telegraf } from 'telegraf'
    
    import { UnlinkScene } from './scenes/unlink.scene'
    import { AppService } from './app.service'
    import { User } from './models/user.model'
    import { BotMessage, getTelegramMessage } from './util/bot_messages'
    import { SceneContext } from 'telegraf/typings/scenes'
    
    @Update()
    export class AppUpdate {
      constructor(
        @InjectBot() private readonly bot: Telegraf<Context>,
        private readonly appService: AppService,
        private readonly unlinkScene: UnlinkScene
      ) {}
    
    
      @Command('unlink')
      unlink(@Ctx() ctx: SceneContext) {
        ctx.scene.enter('unlink')
        return
      }
```

```
unlink.scene.ts
import { AppService } from './../app.service'
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { Action, Ctx, Hears, Next, Scene, SceneEnter } from 'nestjs-telegraf'
import { Markup } from 'telegraf'
import { SceneContext } from 'telegraf/typings/scenes'

import { BotMessage, getTelegramMessage } from 'src/util/bot_messages'

@Injectable()
@Scene('unlinkScene')
export class UnlinkScene {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}
  @SceneEnter()
  async unlinkEnter(@Ctx() ctx: SceneContext) {
    await ctx.replyWithHTML(
      getTelegramMessage(BotMessage.UNLINK),
      Markup.inlineKeyboard([
        Markup.button.callback('Да', 'unlink'),
        Markup.button.callback('Нет', 'link')
      ])
    )
  }

  @Action('unlink')
  async unlinking(
    @Ctx() ctx: SceneContext,
    @Next() next: () => ParameterDecorator
  ) {
    console.log('unlinking')
    await this.appService.unlinkUser((ctx.update as any).callback_query.from.id)
    await ctx.replyWithHTML(getTelegramMessage(BotMessage.UNLINK_YES))
    next()
  }

  @Action('link')
  async linking(
    @Ctx() ctx: SceneContext,
    @Next() next: () => ParameterDecorator
  ) {
    console.log('linking')
    await ctx.replyWithHTML(getTelegramMessage(BotMessage.UNLINK_NO))
    next()
  }
}
```

```
app.module.ts
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config'
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common'
import { TelegrafModule } from 'nestjs-telegraf'
import * as LocalSession from 'telegraf-session-local'

import { AppUpdate } from './app.update'
import { AppService } from './app.service'
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize'
import { User } from './models/user.model'
import { UnlinkScene } from './scenes/unlink.scene'

const session = new LocalSession()

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.env`,
      isGlobal: true
    }),
    TelegrafModule.forRoot({
      middlewares: [session.middleware()],
      token: process.env.TOKEN
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: 'postgres',
      host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
      port: +process.env.POSTGRES_PORT,
      username: process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
      password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
      models: [User],
      autoLoadModels: true
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forFeature([User])
  ],
  providers: [AppService, AppUpdate, UnlinkScene]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Command('unlink') unlink(@Ctx() ctx: SceneContext) { ctx.scene.enter('unlink') return }

Неправильно заходишь в сцену, тебе нужно вызывать ctx.scene.enter('unlinkScene') поскольку у тебя в декораторе @Scene('unlinkScene') unlinkScene это и есть название твоей сцены